# Ideas on filling each shape in triangle mesh with values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write python code that creates a 2D NumPy array (e.g. 128x128) containing a mesh of raster triangles in which each triangle has a random value.

Does anyone know of any python package that could do this?

I tried using this triangle package (https://rufat.be/triangle/examples.html) but i can't seem figure out how to link that to my problem.

The ideal results would be something like this https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/triangle_files/double_hex2.2.ele.png)

but each triangle will show different color because it has different values.

Comment: PyMesh does this, I believe (I haven't tried it, but it seems to support the desired functionality). It has support for the creation of triangular meshes: https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh . Note that it requires several optional geometry-related packages to be installed (including the one for triangular mesh creation).

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking: A 128x128 array of what? You want to render a random triangle mesh with each triangle a different color to a 128x128 pixel bitmap? Do you have the triangle mesh or want to generate a random triangle mesh?

Comment: @jwezorek Sorry if i wasn't clear. I want to create a 128x128 numpy 2D array that has a random triangle mesh with each triangle to a different color/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate *k* random points inside the rectangle (0,0,128,128) and generate the [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of the set of the points plus the four corners of the rectangle.

Construct the NumPy array from the list of triangles by either

1. Implementing the filled triangle rasterization algorithm of your choice -- e.g[. Bresenham's](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html) -- using a NumPy array as the target.
2. or more realistically, painting the triangles into a 128x128 pixel bitmap using a Python raster painting library of your choice and then converting the bitmap to a NumPy array.

Another idea would be to start with a tesselation of equilateral triangles with half triangles along two edges that cover a rectangle, stretch that to cover a square, randomly perturb the vertices, and then do (1) or (2) above ... but this will look less random in that all the internal vertices will have six triangles around them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. What about creating a triangular mesh that contains more uniformly size triangles like [this](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/triangle_files/double_hex2.2.ele.png)?

Comment: if the points you use to generate the Delaunay triangulation are relatively uniformly spaced, the triangles will be too.